# Admob tagForChildDirectedTreatment()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, libgdx, admob

Hi I made a game for under 13 ages.
The problem adding tagForChildDirectedTreatment() code in app.
I found a example but when I try this example I cannot add tagForChildDirectedTreatment()
I think my library does not have tagForChildDirectedTreatment() .

My sdk

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
```

The google example in java

```
    Bundle extras = new Bundle(); extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G");
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
 .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) 
.build();
```

My codes in Kotlin

```
            val extras=Bundle()
            extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G")

        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder()
                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter::class.java, extras)
                /*PROBLEM IS HERE .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) does not exist*/
                .build()



        RewardedAd.load(this, Rewarded_AD_UNIT_ID, adRequest, object : RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdLoaded(p0: RewardedAd) {
                super.onAdLoaded(p0);mRewardedAd = p0
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0);mRewardedAd = null
            }
        })
```

My sdk

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure it globally instead. Call this before `MobileAds.initialize`.

```
val conf = RequestConfiguration.Builder()
    .setMaxAdContentRating("G")
    .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
    .build()
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(conf)
```

Construct your ad request:

```
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
```